# Is it possible to temporary stop a project and payment and then restore it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I set a debian VPS on Google cloud platform. It takes some  monay each day. Is it possible to temporary stop a project and the payment for it and then restore it?

Comment: Why don't you just stop the Debian instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop an instance temporarily and can come back to it at a later time. Keep in mind that a stopped instance does not incur charges, however all of the resources that are attached to the instance will still be charged. For more information regarding stopping an instance please visit this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance). Additionally in regards to your inquiry about temporary stop a project and restore, You can shut down projects using the GCP Console or the [projects.delete() method](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/delete). Shutting down a project does not delete the project immediately, it only requests deletion of the project. The project is marked for deletion ("soft deleted") and you will lose access to it immediately, but the project can be recovered for a 30 day period as this [article](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects) describe. During the 30 day period, the owner can recover the project by following the [steps to restore a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project).